# Google Analytics Data Mismatch between the API Output and the Web Interface

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I generated a Google AdWords Acquisitions report by keyword in three different ways:

The first being by using the Google Analytics web interface; the second by using [GA's Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/); while the third by using the Google Analytics API.

The second and third have a matching number of records of **624 records**. While the first (which I did by using the web interface) generated less: **415 records**.

Yet - the totals for the some of monetary values match in all the three.

Please let me know why this mismatch is happening!

I made sure that the same criteria applies in all three methods but I still couldn't get the three of them to sync.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
query dimension: Campaign
metrics: Clicks, Cost, CPC, Sessions, etc
FILTER (NOT Segment): Source / Medium equals 'google / cpc'